# What are the advantages of ember data and how I can used

Tags: php, zend-framework, ember.js

I noticed a new feature in `ember.js` since RC version. I've been reading about it and I know it now can populate data into a model. But what are the advantages and disadvantages of this? My model its populated through JSON but I don't know if it's the best solution.

The other part of my question is: how can I use the ember data for example with zend framework?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are talking about [Ember Data](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/).  I used this at a company I worked for a few months ago.  At the time it was barely introduced into the main Ember.js repository (we were using it back in the day when it was a second repo called ember-data).  It's a pretty nifty feature that allows for simple/rapid CRUD.  It's specifically designed to work with Ruby on Rails but with some modifications to your backend you can get it to communicate with Ember Data. From their website:

> Without any configuration, Ember Data can load and save records and relationships served via a RESTful JSON API, provided it follows certain conventions.

So its main benefit is rapid development in Ember for communicating with a web service to get and update data.  So if your site is getting and saving data just fine you probably don't need to switch. At least wait until it's in a stable release.  If you're starting a new app and don't plan on releasing to the public and don't mind having to fix breaking changes (trust me they happen weekly) then Ember Data can be a real help!